# Perform Segue from View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I created a view that will look like a splash screen and which will be loaded when the app is first started. I have also created a segue that will take from the initial splash screen to the main view after some certain background tasks have been performed. However, I have no idea how to initiate the segue since I don't have any user interaction within that splash screen. Does anyone have an answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `UIViewController` created from the storyboard, you can start a segue in code using `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`

Comment: Yes, I have tried this before. I inserted this into the 'viewDidLoad' method, but for some reason it doesn't transition at all but rather just leaves the view open.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called before the view is displayed. Try using  `viewDidAppear:` instead, it's called when the view has been displayed.